# Limit user logins in torquebox with torquebox sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, jruby, torquebox

I want to use torquebox and limit a user's logins on a jruby rails app so that he cannot login from multiple browsers.  I did it with activerecord sessions by keeping track of user id's and session id's when someone logged in and invalidating old sessions.

How can I do something similar in Torquebox?  I don't see class methods on TorqueBox::Session module so I can invalidate other sessions, just ways to access the intance.  The mechanics of how the sessions work are not clear.  I am looking here: https://github.com/torquebox/torquebox/tree/2x-dev/gems/web/lib

Answer (score 0):

If you have the current session object stored locally, in say `current_session`:

```
TorqueBox::Session::ServletStore.load_session_data(current_session)
```

This will allow you to view the current session data, and it is accompanied by a sister function which enables you to also set the data in the session store, `store_session_data(...)`:

```
TorqueBox::Session::ServletStore.store_session_data(current_session, data)
```

You can also set `data` to `{}` (empty hash) to invalidate it (for most intents and purposes).

The availability of a current session object will vary depending on scope. For instance, in a stomplet, I must do some introspection on a subscriber to get the `current_session` object in order to see the session data:

```
class ChatStomplet
  # ...

  def on_subscribe (subscriber)
    @subscribers[ session(subscriber)[:current_user].username ] << subscriber
  end

  # ...

  def session (subscriber)
    TorqueBox::Session::ServletStore.load_session_data(subscriber.getSession)
  end
end
```

You should probably have a peek at the [`ActionDispatch::Session::TorqueBoxStore`](http://torquebox.org/documentation/2.1.2/yardoc/ActionDispatch/Session/TorqueBoxStore.html) api, too.

I haven't personally been able to find much documentation on this. As it is, I'm still looking for a way to find all the currently active sessions. It would help if they would implement [AbstractStore's interface](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActionDispatch/Session/AbstractStore), as compatability with current Rails conventions would go a long way.

I know this isn't a complete answer, but hopefully it will shed some light on your travels..

Answer (score 0):

TorqueBox (2.x, at least) stores the Java session ID in `session[:session_id]`. If you need to get it from Middleware it's available in `env['rack.session'][:session_id]`.